# Gaussian RV issue

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, gaussian-integral

I got a problem in exam which is related to Gaussian RV and is as follows:
RV 'W' is a gaussian random variable with $N_w(0,1)$ and Y is a random variable defined as:

$$Y =  W    for |w|<=1 $$
$$Y = -W    for |w|>1 $$

It asks me to derive the covariance matrix of W and Y which I know is a matrix consisting of variance and covariance of W and Y
\begin{bmatrix}
K_y & K_{wy} \\
K_{yw} & K_w
\\
\end{bmatrix}

I know that my variance of Y and W are '1' since pdf of Y is also gaussian with variance '1', how can I find K_{wy} as I need to prove whether Y and W are jointly gaussian or not and I need the covariance matrix to prove that. I was trying to derive through following way:
Since $cov(w,y)= E{(w-E(w)(y-E(y)}$ I am left with $E(WY)$ which is for:

E(WY) = E(y^2) for |y|<=1 $$-$$
E(wy) = E(-y^2) for |y|>1

The first is the variance which is '1' but second gives me variance '-1' which is wrong, can someone help me as to what I am doing wrong, thanks

Comment: @Kimchi, sorry I have corrected it, yes it is range of 'w'

Comment: So $Y$ is some function $g(W)$ of $W$, and you have to work out $EWg(W)$, maybe by using calculus.  To get a handle on things, draw a graph of $w\mapsto g(w)$ and another of $w\mapsto wg(w)$.

Comment: For me, I am confused regarding covariance of y and w. Am I correct to deduce that probability density funcition of $f_Y(y)$ is also gaussian with $N_y(0,1)$ since the range from -1<w<1 is nothing but $f_W(w)$ and for range |w|>1, it is inverted of $f_W(w)$ and as gaussian is symmetric, it will be same. so $f_Y(y)$ must be gaussian also with same mean and variance as of $f_W(w)$. Is it correct to say that Y and W are not independent and must have some covariance as information of W gives me information for Y through above relation. How can I find this covariance?

Comment: You are right, $Y$ and $W$ are not independent, and are not jointly gaussian.  But whoever set the problem up made it the case that $Y$ __is_ a standard gaussian, and all you need to do is evaluate $EYW$, $EY$, and $EW$.  As I commented above, you should draw a graph of how $y$ depends on $w$, and of how $yw$ depends on $w$.